# Get dates from AUT?

Tags: date, vbscript, locale, qtp, hp-uft

My Web-based application (like most) follows the browser locale to format dates.

So if you configure British English as the preferred language in the browser, the app will display dates in "`DD/MM/YYYY`" format.

**Now QTP (ok, it´s VBScript that is the culprit) does not know about this. It strictly follows the local machine´s locale settings.**

Unfortunately, that means that if my local machine is configured to German locale, and the app is in English (because the browser is configured this way), VBScript´s `DateValue` function will fail (because it expects "`DD.MM.YYYY`" format.

**So what is an elegant way to convert an AUT-displayed date value to a native VBScript date so I can do calendar calculations and checks on it?**

Except for switching the current user´s locale to one that matches the browser´s language, I don´t see a solution which avoids having to write decoders/encoders for all kinds of locales myself -- which looks like a huge overkill to me.

For example, a `DateValue` variant which lets me explicitely specify the locale to use would be great. Is there such a thing?

In general, its not just about dates, but every data item that is formatted differently depending on the locale (time specs, currency amounts, floats, ...).

Comment: can you show us any code?

Comment: You ask for a reason, and rightfully so. But -- no, I haven´t approached this in code yet.

Comment: can you use "SetLocale(9)" in your script?

9 -- English

Comment: Yes. or `SetLocale "en"`, and so on. See my own answer.

Comment: if you cannot use SetLocale, for example you cannot use it in .VBS file, you should parse date by yourself 

D = Date
MsgBox(Year(D) & "-" & Month(D) & "-" & Day(D))

Comment: It seems that within QTP, `SetLocale` and `GetLocale` manipulate the locale QTP uses. So I can use those functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure about QTP, but the windows scripting host handles it via `SetLocale`

```
Option Explicit

Dim originalLocale
    originalLocale = GetLocale()

Dim aLocales
    aLocales = Array("en-us", "es-es", "de")

Dim locale, aDates, d

    For Each locale in aLocales
        WScript.Echo locale
        SetLocale locale

        aDates = Array( Date(), DateValue("01/02/2015"))
        For Each d in aDates
            WScript.Echo FormatDateTime(d, 1)
            WScript.Echo FormatDateTime(d, 2)
        Next 
        WScript.Echo "-------------------------------------------------"
    Next

    SetLocale originalLocale
```

Answer (score 2):

While it is said (by Microsoft, see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176965.aspx) that `GetLocale` and `SetLocale` are usable only in WebPages, those functions are exactly what I was looking for. And they work within QTP.

To convert a date value from the AUT (being a string) to a VBScript date value, I

- call `GetLocale` to fetch and save the original locale
- call `SetLocale` to switch to the same locale as the browser´s (read from registry)
- use `DateValue` to convert the string to a native date (or use any other locale-sensitive routine)
- call `SetLocale` with the original setting to switch back to the original locale.

Interestingly, QTP always starts a test´s execution with the system locale active -- even if the last test execution did leave behind a different locale set active.

See f.e. https://support.microsoft.com/de-de/kb/232158/en-us