# VBScript Convert value to Date

Tags: vbscript, date-conversion

I have a VBScript that runs on the developer machine, in which the following line of code

```
CDate("01/09/2017")
```

returns the date as 1 September 2017.

But when deployed on certain clients the same line of code returns 9 January 2017 as the date.

How can I control this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [has been answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30777816/692942) before in detail;

Use [`SetLocale()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5xf99h19(v=vs.84).aspx) to choose how you want VBScript to interpret the value.

```
SetLocale(1106) 'Set to United Kingdom
WScript.Echo CDate("01/09/2017")
```

For valid Locale ID values see [Microsoft Locale ID Values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms912047(WinEmbedded.10).aspx) *(you also appear to able to use valid [IETF language tag codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IETF_language_tag) as well like `en-us` etc)*.

Comment: Might also want to [`GetLocale()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d457t70w(v=vs.84).aspx) to cache the current locale first, then reset for other regional dependent items afterward

Comment: @oraclecertifiedprofessional just like the linked answer shows.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the date string is parsed according to the regional settings of the respective system. For stable results across systems with different regional settings you probably need to parse the date yourself, e.g. like this:

```
s = "01/09/2017"
a = Split(s, "/")
d = DateSerial(a(2), a(1), a(0))
```